# angularjs ng-repeat index or data ref in element ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have a back reference to the data used by ng-repeat.  Is a data reference or the $index associated with an element persisted anywhere in the dom or elements ?

Comment: I'm trying writing an editor framework for angularjs.. I'd like to provide a clear framework to integrate widget frameworks ie. jquery-ui and highcharts. ng-repeat injects the template and object data into the dom. However, I don't have a reverse reference to the data. I can find the ng-repeat attribute in the parent identifying the source data object list/array. I don't have a way to id the specific instance in the list/array.

I could inject an attribute into the elements, but would prefer to use something already in place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not by default but you can easily store the info on DOM element if you really need it.

I edited the example from Angular docs http://plnkr.co/edit/s4JxOkEBHNsRObBWq1hc?p=preview

Look at `data-index`:

```
<li class="animate-repeat" data-index="{{ $index }}" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
        [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</li>
```

Comment: I would like to add data-index="{{ $index }}" to ng-repeat.. so its transparent. Any suggestions ?